# How to implement ViewModel with FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, viewmodel, android-jetpack

I am trying to separate my database from my UI controller using ViewModel and prevent constant data usage. I have searched for solution for days now without any headway.
I am using Firebase RecyclerAdapter in my app and the code is working well, but I don't know how to implement a LiveData Observer with the RecyclerAdapter.
any sample app or snippet will be of great help to me.

> Here is a sample code from my Fragment

```
private void fetchValues() {
    Query query1 = mDatabaseReference;

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Course> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Course>()
            .setQuery(query1, new SnapshotParser<Course>() {
                @NonNull
                @Override
                public Course parseSnapshot(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                    return new Course(snapshot.child("course_title").getValue().toString(),
                            snapshot.child("course_code").getValue().toString(),
                            snapshot.child("course_lecturer").getValue().toString());
                }
            })
            .build();

    mFirebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Course, CourseViewHolder>(options){
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public CourseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            mCourseItemBinding = CourseItemBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()), parent, false);
            View view = mCourseItemBinding.getRoot();
            return new CourseViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CourseViewHolder holder, int position, Course course) {
            holder.bind(course);
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), String.valueOf(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }
    };

    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFirebaseRecyclerAdapter);
}
```

Comment: As I see, you are using the Firebase-UI library which provides real-time updates but I cannot see any code related to ViewModel or LivedData in what you have already shared.

Comment: Like I said, I don't know how to go about that using the Firebase-UI. Any tips will be of great help

Comment: As far as I know, it is not a good idea to mix MVVM pattern and Firebase-UI. You can use either one of them. Use Firebase-UI and implement in fragment or activity or fetch the data separately from firebase in view model and pass it to fragment or activity using observers.